# How to connect a gateway in Azure iot Central

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

recently MS has released a new feature regarding IoT-Central.
One of these features is about connecting an Iot-Node/Device to Iot-Central as Gateway.
Since I haven't found any documentation about it, I would like to know if anyone knows how to use it.

Thank you very much for your efforts in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about the newly announced preview for connecting IoT Edge devices (for use as gateways) to IoT Central, here is the corresponding tutorials to get started:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/tutorial-define-edge-device-type-pnp
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/tutorial-add-edge-as-leaf-device

Note that this feature is still in preview. As a general note, to find documentation for preview features in IoT Central, you can find the link at the root of the IoT Central documentation for the generally available features (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/overview-iot-central-pnp).

Comment: thank you very much for the info! :) Do you by any means know if this preview is command and device twin compatible? thanks again ~

Comment: @user12117069 not sure I understand the question. Can you clarify? Maybe post a new question with more context/details.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests using IOT Central. The way I found to connect a device to IOT Central Hub was using DPS Key Gen to generate the connection string, then use it to send data.

https://github.com/Azure/dps-keygen

More info in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-connectivity

Ps: this blog post was very helpful too: https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2019/04/06/connecting-simple-devices-to-iot-central/

Comment: thank you very much as well. Indeed the connection string helps you to access Telemetry Data as an Json string send by your IoT device. Prior to that release you had to aquire the con string very diffrently :) much  appreciation for the effort.